# Why is Maatanos Levyonim not mentioned in regards to the bracha of שהחיינו?

Tags: blessing, shehecheyanu

The Mechaber (692:1) writes that one makes a שהחיינו on the megillah . The Mishna Brurah notes that one should have in mind the mitzvah of Mishloach Manos and Seudas purim when the bracha of שהחיינו is made. Why is matonos levyonim omitted? The Be' er Heitiv seems to bring thos from the Shla Hakodosh.

Text of MB:
(א) ושהחיינו – ונכון לכוין בברכת שהחיינו גם על משלוח מנות וסעודת פורים שהם ג״כ מצות ויודיע זה להש״ץ המברך דבעי כונת שומע ומשמיע.

Text of Shla Hakadosh:
כשמברכין על קריאת מגילה ושהחיינו יכוין שיוצא בברכות אלו גם על סעודת פורים שיאכל ומצות משלוח מנות כו' כי סעודות פורים ומשלוח מנות הם ג"כ מצות מדברי קבלה וראוי היה לברך עליהם אקב"ו כו'

Comment: I assume because technically one must give charity year-round.

Comment: Did you check the shla inside

Comment: The chyiuv of tzedaka is an amount not similar to ML. @doubleAA ,I did not get a chance to check yet. Does he discuss why it's omitted?

Comment: Added the Shla ,is ML not mdivrei kabala

Comment: Maybe כו'  is איש לרעהו ומתנות לאביונים?

Comment: :/ .............

Answer (score 3):

As you note, the MA and MB following the language of the Shelah absent the obligation of מתנות לאביונים when discussing the blessing of שהחיינו. However other sources, such as חיי אדם,  פרי מגדים, שולחן שלמה , do exhort one to keep it in mind when reciting the blessing.

In תורה ודעת (vol. 4, p. 109) Rabbi Yishayah Sirota analyzes the question and suggests that the difference in perspective is part of a larger debate (with other נפקא מינות emerging from this distinction) over whether one views מתנות לאביונים as an extension of the always extant misvah to give sedaqa or whether it is a new institution created by the Hakhamim out of whole cloth.

Here is the article:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have time to translate the relevant sections at the moment, if anyone else wants to take a crack at it.

Comment: The article doesn't seem to draw any conclusions on the topic beyond citing sources.

Comment: @N.T. no it does not offer a conclusion. However paragraphs 3 and 4 set up a framework within which to view the discrepant perspectives and thus offers a tentative answer to the initial Q as I understood it ("*why* does the MB/Shelah not mention מתנות לאביונים alongside the other מצוות היום when it comes to the recitation of שהחיינו?").